# Triggering spell check in InDesign using COM

Tags: com, adobe-indesign

How can I begin the spell check process for selected text / all text using the COM interface? There's an executeMenuCommand for javascript, but seems like there's no alternative for the COM interface.

Answer (score 0):

I hate it when this happens! I walk away, and take a stab from a different angle!

`((InDesign.MenuAction)app.MenuActions["Check Spelling..."]).Invoke();`

Where app is the COM application. The cast is unnecessary, but allows you to see the properties of the menu action.